# What settings should I use in the Key node if the green background is very uneven?

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor

**EDIT #3**

The original title of this thread was: "Why is alpha-over node not as good as in the VSE?" and I think the best answer to that is  from @troy_s:

> You have to remember that the compositor and the VSE operate in radically different ways, so don't expect a correspondence between values.

Since then the discussion has moved on to Key node settings, so I am changing the question. For reference, the original post follows ...

I am making some video presentations of student art work, where the students are keyed over their art.

I started by saving the keyed "talent" as .png sequences and using the VSE to overlay that on top of the art.

[image: from VSE]

This is acceptable considering the video was taken with a tablet, using green corrugated PVC board as a green-screen.

But the process is very time-consuming and I have about 600 shots to do!

So it occurred to me that I should be able to put everything together in the compositor to make it more efficient.

However, the Alpha Over node in the compositor is making parts of the "talent" transparent.

[image]

At first I suspected the output from the Keying node. Somehow, it might not be the same as a .png file. So, to trouble-shoot, I tried using the same frame from the .png image sequence instead of the direct output, but the result is the same either way.

[image: node setup using .png image file]

So, before I go back to saving everything as .png sequences, can anyone tell me a way to get the Alpha Over node to behave the same as the Alpha Over VSE effect?

**EDIT #1**

Thanks to @cegaton for getting involved. Here is the .png image.

[image]

And here is the original node setup before I started trouble-shooting.

[image]

I really can't see how the .png could be the problem because:

1. Originally, I was trying to take the output directly from the Key node without saving to a .png; and
2. The .png sequence works as expected in the VSE - it produced the (acceptable) image at the top of the page.

In fact saving to a .png sequence **solves** the problem (in that I can use it in the VSE) rather than causing it. But I'd prefer to avoid that as it's time-consuming.

**EDIT #2**

@cegaton Oh dear! I really wish I'd made no mention of PNG as it has been a distraction.

To clarify:

1. If you look at the original node setup (i.e. the one after EDIT #1) there is no hint of a PNG image anywhere.
2. The problem is that, **using that node setup**, I noticed that the keyed output had some bleed through from the background image.
3. I didn't know whether the problem was with the Key node or the Alpha Over node, so I used a standard trouble-shooting technique to find which one was the culprit.
4. It was only then that I tried replacing the Key node with the Image node, since the PNG sequence worked well in the VSE.
5. I actually suspected that my Key node settings were at fault, and
   was surprised that replacing the Key node with the Image node
   **produced exactly the same results!**

[image: node comparison]

6. So, since a) the Key node and Image node produced the same results in the compositor, and b) the Alpha Over effect in the VSE produced much better results, the logical conclusion is that either:

   - the Alpha Over node is somehow different to the Alpha Over effect in the VSE; or
   - the VSE is feeding the Alpha Over effect differently to the way the compositor feeds the Alpha Over node.

So, not using PNG images cannot be part of the solution because I wasn't using them in the compositor before I started trouble-shooting.

However, I think @cegaton is probably right in that the solution is in adjusting the Key node settings. I suspect what is actually happening is that the VSE is somehow disguising the problem with the keying.

I just wish I could find a way to replicate whatever the VSE is doing in the compositor!

**EDIT #4**

Thanks to all for the contributions so far. Here is a screenshot of the original video.

[image: unkeyed image]

As you can see, the variation in green colour makes keying very difficult. I am used to chromakey where there is a setting called "tolerance" or something similar. I also vaguely remember stacking chromakeys in Kdenlive for severe cases such as this where the bottom panel is so much darker than the others.

The Key node in Blender is much better because it has "Despill" but I do miss the tolerance setting. Reading the Blender manual, I think I need to replace the single "Key Color" with a range, but I'm not sure how to do that.

As usual any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Does the image you are overlaying have an alpha channel? If so, how was that created? Please show more images of the elements used.

Comment: Thanks for the query @cegaton. Yes, the image in the final example does have an alpha channel. It is a .png created by blender with rgba set in the output section. I deliberately did not include the node setup that created that image, because it works fine with the VSE Alpha Over effect.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the image and it's alpha channel. PNG is a terrible format as it doesn't do proper associated alpha, maybe the problem is there, but I am terrible at guessing and speculating, I prefer information and facts.... For all I know, the compositor's alpha over node works fine with images that have a proper alpha channel. How was that alpha channel created out of the green background?

Comment: Thanks again for the ideas @cegaton. Please the the revised question beginning at "Edit #1".

Comment: Can you post the original greenscreen image you used in your sample as well as the background plate? You have to remember that the compositor and the VSE operate in radically different ways, so don't expect a correspondence between values.

Comment: @troy_s You're right in that the green-screen image is the root of the problem. I was shooting in a chaotic classroom with green corrugated PVC taped together with green gaffer tape, and a combination of fluorescent light and whatever other light happened to come through the windows! So the fact that the VSE works so well is something of a miracle. Meanwhile, I've just discovered that we have a 10+ hour blackout tomorrow, and I'd really like to finish this project by the end of the week, so I'm going to bite the bullet and use the VSE for now. Thanks for the input.

Comment: How did you perform the key in the VSE? Or does the boy image already have an alpha channel? Anyway did you try the premult option in the Alpha over node?

Comment: @3pointedit Yes, I started off using the Key node in the compositor to make a PNG sequence, and loaded that into the VSE. That works well, but seems inefficient. I did try fiddling with premult, and various other things, but ultimately, the problem is the source material (the green is too inconsistent), and I haven't been able to replicate whatever is happening in the VSE in the compositor.

Comment: As Troy noted the VSE composites differently to the compositor and there is a node to alter the comp output to accommodate that.

Comment: @Thailandian please don't change the question to accommodate for an answer. This site is not a forum, where "threads" start as being one thing and end up being another, but a simple question and answer site. You wrote and accepted an answer for the original question which was indeed the answer to your original issue. Now you have a totally different question than the original one, and now the answers provided, while similar do not match anymore... don't use your post as an organic " work in progress" or " personalized help". Please use different posts for different questions.

Comment: @cegation Sorry about that. That was actually my intention but the process got away from me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the default settings for the keying node.

[image: Partially transparent key]

Change the Clip white and clip black to make the key more dense.

[image: Improved matte clip values]

To test this, replace your background with a hot pink or yellow color image. This will make the partially transparent regions more obvious.

***Before adjustment:***
[image: failed test]

***After adjustment:***
[image: passed test]

You can use a Chroma Key node to create the core matte. This does the heavy lifting of cutting out your main shape. Then you use the Keying node to soften the edges. I have introduced a mask to cut out the extra wall on the side.

[image: improved key]

Comment: Thanks for this. I have now changed the thread title to suit where the discussion has led. Also, please see EDIT #4 for a screenshot of my original video. That should give a better idea of what I'm up against!

Comment: Wow - that's fantastic @3pointedit! I'd started to get much better results using just the first part of your answer, but this is better again. The colour ramp was a big part of what I was looking for, but I also realise that the Edge Kernel, Clip Black and Clip White together perform a function akin to chroma-key "tolerance" (I guess it's "acceptance" in Blender.

Comment: One thing I haven't been able to get so far is the view of the alpha channel of either the Viewer Node or Render Result. As soon as I select that, I get all white regardless of what Clip Black and Clip White are set to. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes you cannot see the alpha channel after passing through the Alpha Over node. You must get it directly from the Keying node.

Comment: Also good luck with the big job ahead. After all this I should point pout that you can in fact make a chromakeyer in the VSE. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78947/how-can-i-do-color-keying-using-the-vse and my tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mVm4hwO0EU

Answer (score 3):

First read [this related answer:](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104642/partly-ignored-png-alpha/104658#104658)

Now on to the issue at hand:

Open your image in the UV/Image editor and look at the RGB and Alpha information:

[image]

Your alpha channel is not as solid as you would nee it to be, all of those black and gray spots on the mask prevent the mask from being opaque...

Plus the RBG channel contains information that should not be there (alpha is not associated)

[image]

How to fix it:

- Rework your settings for the key and get a cleaner mask
- Associate the alpha channel to your output image.(see: [Partly Ignored PNG Alpha?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104642/partly-ignored-png-alpha/104658#104658))
- Avoid PNG and use other fomats like EXR or TIF
- Use alpha over with the same node tree you are currently using to composite and things should be fine.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46312/how-can-i-associate-the-alpha-channel-so-that-it-works-with-the-alpha-over-node

Comment: *Avoid PNG and use other fomats like EXR or TIF.* > Why (in this case)? Benefits?

Comment: @Leander  look for the many posts on this site on why PNG sucks (just do a search on this site for "PNG" and "associated alpha"). EXR uses a proper associated alpha channel, on top of keeping information linearly.

Comment: Cegaton's answers are on point. I'd only add @Leander that only associated alpha represents a physically plausible model that represents _emission_ (the RGB values) and _occlusion_ (the alpha channel). This means that they can be operated on in tandem as though they are four equal channels. Convolutions, rotoscopes, emissions without occlusions (candles, glows, lens flares), etc. all _only_ behave correctly when associated. Without associated alpha, rotoscopes will fringe / bleed, convolutions will contaminate, and glows / flares / blooms are impossible.

Comment: Sorry @cegation, but the PNG part of your answer does not address the question. Please see EDIT #2 for clarification.

Comment: Bad news @cegaton, despite TIFFs being associated alpha without additional tags and planes, try loading an 8 bit TIFF with Blender. The cancerous design spread to everything 8 bit.

Answer (score 1):

For practical reasons, I'm going to have to leave this for the moment, but first, want to highlight this quote from  @troy_s:

> You have to remember that the compositor and the VSE operate in radically different ways, so don't expect a correspondence between values.

That is the most direct answer to my question: "Why is alpha-over node not as good as in the VSE?"

Everything else has been useful and interesting, but that is the answer I needed, so it would have been a shame if it went unnoticed.

Comment: If you can provide the original still image someone here can pull a good key for you. In your PNG in your answer, there are two problems with it. First it is a PNG, and as a result, the image isn't in the correct alpha format for the Alpha Over node, which assumes Associated Alpha. Second, you have an alpha value of < 1.0 in regions of the head, which is why you are getting bleed through. The key pull is at fault and is easily corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @troy_s. As I've said, the PNG part is irrelevant because what I'm trying to do is go directly from the Key node to the Alpha Over node. But help with the keying itself is a good idea. As I hinted at in a previous comment, the root problem is that the green is too variable because of the lighting. And I can't work out how to make a colour range for the Key node input. Rather than a screen cap still, I'll upload a short example video somewhere and post a link. If anyone would like to have a go at it, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: You aren't listening to what I and others are trying to impress upon you; the PNG _is_ part of the problem. Your alpha is unassociated and that means that it is _not_ suitable for feeding into the alpha over node without the poorly labelled "convert premul" box checked. The other part is simply unfortunate values in the keying node, whatever you are using. I'd be happy to pull a key off of a still image if you can post one, and I'll provide you the node group. Video can work too.

Comment: @troy_s I'll try to explain with a metaphor. Suppose that my problem is "I fear for my safety" and part of your answer is "Well you shouldn't live in Afghanistan". While that is undoubtedly good advice in a general sense, it is not part of my problem because I don't live in Afghanistan! Please understand, I'm not trying to downplay what you and others are saying about PNGs, but if you look at the SECOND node setup (i.e. before I started trouble-shooting), I wasn't using a PNG, so logically, PNGs cannot be part of that problem.

Comment: @troy_s I thought I should separate the parts of my response for clarity. I was actually planning to start a new thread for the sake of search engines, but since 3pointedit has already posted an answer relating to the Key node, I'll change the title of this one. Thanks again for your offer of help. And you're right, working with a still should give a pretty good indication of the key settings I need.

Comment: I don't believe the advice was entirely non sequitor. "My key pull is bad" had two components. One, rightly, was that the code is different and your settings needed to be adjusted. The other, _in the case of the original plate you offered_, was a byproduct of the file format chosen. It is a fair answer when it points out all reasons your key pull was off.