# Keying and Masking Green Screen but Background Isn't Transparent

Tags: masking

I have green screen footage that I'm trying to render with a transparent background.  I create a mask and set up my nodes in the compositer, but the result in the viewer and in renders has a checkered background with distorted colors (see image).  What is the issue? I can see and account for all nodes going into compositing, so there shouldn't be anything else. Film is set to transparent, sequencer is toggled off, and I don't have a clip editor tab open. Conceptually, I can tell that the mask and keying is working, but then it's adding back in the checkered background. I have read everything I could find and watched many tutorials.  I am out of ideas. I'm sure this is a noob mistake and I'm ready to eat crow. Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: There is a bug in the node. You need to convert the alpha to premultiplied , or update to Version 2.92, where the bug is fixed. Read: Keying node in compositor. [How can I associate the alpha channel so that it works with the Alpha Over Node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46312/keying-node-in-compositor-how-can-i-associate-the-alpha-channel-so-that-it-work)

Comment: @susu - Thank you! I updated to 2.92 and it works great now.