# How to use more GPU memory to render faster?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

When I render a scene the GPU memory usage is only ~10% even less than that (477Mb). Is there any way to use more of the GPU memory and make the rendering process faster?
I render each frame at the time if that helps.

Setup:

- Blender 2.8
- Ubuntu 18.04
- GTX 1060

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You could try increasing BVH Time Steps. The tooltip seems to say it it might be what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Tried that, I have changed it to 16 but still only ~477 Mb was used. and each frame took 6.45 seconds to render.

Comment: If a frame takes seconds to render, it could be because of other processes like writing file to disk or preparing and loading the scene, not because of the actual rendering. This might be as good as it gets. Most CG artists dream of renders taking 6.45 seconds anyway, me including. My renders take days literally, for example. Render times in seconds are already very fast.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my animation is really basic one without any fancy things involved. the time it takes to render scene is identical when the output is PNG or AVI, tried that before.

Comment: PNG is very slow format to write to disk. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148231/what-image-format-encodes-the-fastest-or-at-least-faster-png-is-too-slow You could try more formats see if it makes a difference.