# Blender 2.79. Cycles Render. Output of animation in PNG Sequence. Level of compression

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, compression

Do you use level of compression = 0 when you make output of animation in PNG Sequence?

There is field Compression in Blender. Available values from 0 to 100.

If to move cursor to this field explanation appears:

> Amount of time to determine best compression: 0 = no compression with
>   fast file output, 100 = maximum lossless compression with slow file
>   output.

I work in Windows 10 Home 64-bit. Blender 2.79. Cycles Render.

Comment: no compression, you'll compress the video after you created it.

Comment: No compression means large file size but faster encoding. That's the trade-off. The compression is lossless though, so you're not losing any quality.

Comment: @sanbaldo. Thank you. In which situation you will use no compression? In which situation you will use compression level = 100? In which situation you will use some other compression level? For example compression level = 50?

Comment: @Robert Gützkow. Thank you. In which situation you will use no compression? In which situation you will use compression level = 100? In which situation you will use some other compression level? For example compression level = 50?

Comment: Since bit depth, file size and encoding speed is better with OpenEXR, I'd use that as intermediate format before rendering the image sequence into a video. Like I said before, pngs compression is quite slow. If you need to use png as format and it should save the frames quickly, use a lower compression ratio. If file size needs to be smaller, use a larger compression ratio. Perhaps this answer explains the situation a bit better: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148231/what-image-format-encodes-the-fastest-or-at-least-faster-png-is-too-slow/148466#148466

Comment: @Robert Gützkow. Thank you, Robert. I took in attention you use OpenEXR as intermediate format before rendering the image sequence into a video. I read the materials from the link https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148231/what-image-format-encodes-the-fastest-or-at-least-faster-png-is-too-slow/148466#148466 Thank you. Why some people use PNG Sequence instead of OpenEXR Sequence?

Comment: Good question. Perhaps they simply don't know about the benefits of using OpenEXR.

Comment: @Robert Gützkow. I think so too. And why some people use DPX Sequence instead of OpenEXR Sequence?