# Targa versus PNG for Image Texture

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

I have noticed in cycles I render faster with .tga image textures than .png image textures. Is there a loss in render quality because of using targas instead of pngs? Which should I use?

Comment: Hello :). This sounds interesting. Would you mind adding more details? Image resolution, render time difference, map type...  Just curious :).

Comment: The answer is: EXR.

Comment: Hello @troy_s :). Doesn't the OP mean material image textures, not the output file?

Comment: Materials are the same answer. EXR is exemplary on all fronts, and is in many instances the only means to get things like reflections etc. into Blender. EXR is the only sane option for speed, size, quality, and encoding.

Answer (score 0):

PNG takes longer to read or write, because the computer needs to compress it. Therefore it takes up less space. TGA is largely uncompressed, so it's being written and read faster, but takes up more space. Both formats are loss-less, but I think the color range of TGA is larger.
Targa is popular in Game Enginges because the Alpha channel is independent from the color channels and it reads very fast. EXR is usually the largest, but it supports HDR. I haven't tested it, but it should be read faster than PNG.

Comment: EXR can be smaller in size: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148231/what-image-format-encodes-the-fastest-or-at-least-faster-png-is-too-slow/148466#148466

Comment: Hello :). Doesn't the OP mean image textures used in materials, instead of an output file?

Comment: You're correct, ups, but my answer works both ways. PNG ofc. also takes longer to decompress as it does to compress.

Comment: I was referring to image textures for shaders. I almost always render in multi-layer exr.

Comment: Changed it, so it's more suitable.