# Save render for compositing

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Is there a way to save render so you can manipulate it in compositor even after turning off and back on the program. Yes I know I can use image node but it doesn't have cryptomattes.

Comment: Hello :). The best way is to save all your passes/layers into a 32-bit EXR. That basically backs up your render result so you can get back to it anytime.

Comment: Related: [Save all render passes to EXR image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image/18406#18406)

Answer (score 3):

Just to save your render and all your channels like mist, light passes, cryptomattes etc. to [OpenEXR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR) which allows to store all the data you need in order to comp your renders in a next stage or at any given time.

From Wikipedia:

> OpenEXR is a high-dynamic range, multi-channel raster file format ... It is notable for supporting multiple channels of potentially different pixel sizes, including 32-bit unsigned integer, 32-bit and 16-bit floating point values, as well as various compression techniques which include lossless and lossy compression algorithms. It also has arbitrary channels and encodes multiple points of view such as left- and right-camera images.

Further reading:

- [OpenEXR in the Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/media/image_formats.html#openexr)
- [Save all render passes to EXR image?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-exr-image)
- [What image format encodes the fastest, or at least faster? PNG is too slow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148231/what-image-format-encodes-the-fastest-or-at-least-faster-png-is-too-slow/148466#148466)