# what can i do to prepare for an overnight render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have a really large animation in cycles that I want to leave to render overnight. how should I prepare? would pointing any fans at my computer cool it a little? i just want to be extra safe about this

Comment: Render to OpenEXR files, use an APC if you have one, and pray to God.

Comment: 2 things. i was under the impression that open EXR was a bit harder to render than png. also what is an APC?

Comment: @desperrrr https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/148231/73575 is a question on various image formats. Basically, OpenEXR is fast, flexible, and not too big. By APC I mean the company that makes uninterruptible power supplies, or rather their products.

Comment: EXR will be the best quality but it is much bigger than PNG and JPG, JPG being the lowest quality. You should make some tests with one image

Comment: EXR has the advantage of storing 32bit images which is good if you are going to use them for compositing after you saved them. And if you use the DWAA or DWAB codec there is no significant loss in quality - and then the file is even smaller than PNG. And if you are using glow on transparent backgrounds for example you will never get back what you see in the render result if you're using PNG or JPG (JPG doesn't even support transparency).

Comment: About the cooling fans: don't know if this is necessary with your hardware... I would rather run out of GPU memory before my card is overheated. And APC is a company that produces UPS devices.