# Emission is not visible when imported into Photoshop (Emission on Transparency i.e. Alpha 0)

Tags: emission

I'm importing a PNG file which has been rendered with Emission shader, but when I import the PNG file into Photoshop  the emission is only very faintly visible, but in Blender render viewport its more apparent.

[image]

Comment: Which export format are you using?

Comment: It looks like you lost your alpha channel somehow.

Comment: PNG format RGBA

Comment: I opened your image in GIMP and sampled the pixel colors around the blue square in the bottom image. They are hex 393939 the same as everywhere else in your image. Either Blender didn't save an alpha channel or Photoshop didn't load it. Can you share your output PNG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in PNG images themselves, that save alpha channels in straight mode (not premultiplied).

Photoshop (and others softwares) multiplies the emission value with the alpha value (wich can be very close to 0) resulting in attenuating the glow effect.

To solve, use EXR instead of PNG, everywhere you need both emission and transparency.

See this answer (and others from this user) for further details: [Why should I never ever use "Convert Premul" on Cycles renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46151/why-should-i-never-ever-use-convert-premul-on-cycles-renders/46197#46197)

Comment: So this is a feature only for cycles? I'm using EEVEE for convenient reasons. I did try EXR file, and when I import into PS I get 2 options, One is the image with the emission but it has a black background even I have transparency chosen. And the other option I choose, brings in just a white shape. So I guess even wont get the job done?

Comment: Cycles or Eevee doesn't matter, but it's a quite complicated issue. The operation works fine if your exported EXR is composited over your background image with a correct "Alpha over" premultiplied fusion option (which is not what PS does, while others compositing softwares can perform).