# Some textures missing after rendering and saving as PNG

Tags: rendering

[image: After rendering]

[image: After saving as the rendered image]

As you can see the pink glowing textures (forming the bow at the back) are gone once I save it as PNG but in the render preview it looks perfectly fine, any clue why?

Comment: What version of blender you use? Possibly related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164940/2214

Comment: Hi :). PNG doesn't support both emissive and transparent pixels. It's a limitation of the format. For compositing use EXR.

Comment: @JachymMichal Oh I had no idea about that, is EXR widely accepted when it comes to editing software like Photoshop and such?

Comment: Hi :). EXR is a gold standard in vfx, not so much with Photoshop afaik. Search this site, [for similar posts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/238524/78972), it's a quite common problem. One solution is to save the alpha as a separate BW mask. Good luck ;)