# Saved PNG is very different from the rendered image

Tags: rendering

it looks like this

[image]

how can i save it as png and have same color and glaring fx?

Comment: Did you try using 16 bit depth (instead of the default 8)? PNG also lets you choose the compression level - default is 15% - maybe try turning to 0?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239795/why-is-my-saved-png-not-as-good-as-the-render/239804#239804

Comment: It's on a different background, make sure you use the same BG twice to rule out optical illusions. Also make sure you checked RGBA in the image format.