# Exporting a 3d animated title with LOTS of emission to video editing software

Tags: emission

I am a noob, but I made a really awesome 3d title animation that I want to overlay on some footage I shot.

I have tried exporting to png sequence but soo much of the cool emission data is lost when I put it in my video sequence.

My questions are as follows;

1. Is there a format with an alpha channel that saves all of that yummy detail, which I can then import into premier pro/after affects, DaVinci etc
2. Would it be possible to bring the clip into blender, overlay the 3d animation on top of the video and then export without losing quality of the video?

This may be a stupid question and thanks for taking the time to read (:(:(:

Comment: I'm not sure what detail is being lost, but I think you are talking about dynamic range. PNG only saves brightness between 0% to 100%, but EXR can store any value. Working with HDR content in a video editor is very complicated though, especially if it is mixed with SDR content.

Comment: I guess what I mean, is that in my render there is all this glare and light particles being reflected off the shape and inhabiting the "empty" space around the shape, though once converted to png it's just the shape.
If you know what I mean

Comment: Ah, that's an issue with the different ways an alpha channel can be interpreted by software. Here's a video that explains the basics: https://youtu.be/XobSAXZaKJ8 The good news is that there is an objectively correct solution out there, the bad news is that I can't find it myself. There's some combinations of settings in Blender and your video editor that will work.

Comment: See this answer for information on this topic: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239795/why-is-my-saved-png-not-as-good-as-the-render/239804?r=SearchResults&s=23%7C0.0000#239804