# Different color Between Video as plane and the Scene

Tags: camera, video-sequence-editor, video, color, chromakey

What is the best way to put a video of dancers inside a 3D scene??

I put the video of the dancers as plane background but the color of the People in alpha channel are
Completely different that the color in the scene and also looks like Blurry.

How can i fit the color with the one in scene?

I also don't want my video to go slow in an active camera view.

Comment: Thanks about the emission and color management Regarding the blender file setting I will check and let you know

Comment: Please share your blend via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Related: [adding multiple green screen plates into an animated 3D envirnonment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45877/adding-multiple-green-screenplates-into-an-animated-3d-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [compositing video layers in 3D space](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/compositing-video-layers-in-3d-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have inserted the video with the add-on "Import images as planes". If not, you can enable this free add-on (menu Edit > Preference > Add-ons. Search for Images and enable the add-on).

When inserting the video, you should choose for "Emit" in the material Settings (see figure 1). That way, the colors of the video are more independent from your lightning setup in the scene. If the colors still loooked a little washed-out, may be you can change the Color Management > View Transform from Filmic to Standard in the Render Properties tab (see figure 2).

About the speed of the video. It's hard to tell without further info. Are the frames per second of the original video and your blend file settings the same?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thank you very much I will let you know about file setting in blender